# Как вывести число с одним знаком после запятой?

Tags: swift

На примере видно что `String(format: "%.1f" , num))` округляет `num`, но как это сделать без округления, как вывести `9.2`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте предварительное округление вручную

```
print(String(format: "%.1f", floor(num * 10) / 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
formatter.roundingMode = .down

print(formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: num)) as Any)
```